# see if there is a deleted part in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

when someone don't pull the latest master and then push he sees a conflict
if he decided to overwrite the others code the overwritten commit don't show in the files history

the issue can be seen here
https://github.com/robertIsaac/delete-test

here you can see that i added second commit
https://github.com/robertIsaac/delete-test/pull/1/files

and here you can see i deleted the second commit and added the third commit
https://github.com/robertIsaac/delete-test/pull/2/files

but going to the history of the file 
https://github.com/robertIsaac/delete-test/commits/master/delete-test.txt
you see only the first and third commit which shows the addition of the first commit and third commit string to the file and second commit doesn't show at all

here is my script to replicate the issue

```
# delete-test script
# you need to create a repo named delete-test 
# and replace the https://github.com/robertIsaac by your user name in the two lines using them
# the second next two lines can be skipped if its your first time running the script
rm -rf ~/github
rm -rf ~/delete-test
mkdir ~/github
cd ~/github
echo "first commit" >> delete-test.txt
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/robertIsaac/delete-test.git
git push -u origin master
git pull
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/robertisaac/delete-test.git
cd ~/github
git checkout -b first-branch
echo "second commit" >> delete-test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "second commit"
git push origin first-branch

## go merge with master (no conflict)

cd ~/delete-test
git checkout -b second-branch
echo "third commit" >> delete-test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "third commit"
git push origin second-branch

## go merge and resolve conflict by accepting second-branch changes and deleting the master changes
```

my question is if i faced a problem like that again how can i catch it without searching every pull request to see who deleted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting, I did not know this problem until now.

Looks like `git log --follow delete-test.txt` is the solution.

```
commit a0d607f5c80f2d9130bd197d9c0af1199515e8cf
Author: robertisaacBBN <robert.isaac@businessboomers.net>
Date:   Sat Dec 1 00:46:06 2018 +0200

    third commit

commit 168d67c24ec1de7e20c645274f64f151592d938f (origin/first-branch)
Author: robertisaacBBN <robert.isaac@businessboomers.net>
Date:   Sat Dec 1 00:45:22 2018 +0200

    second commit

commit 6b488fffd4b0581888e0942249a7b81e68d7db4b
Author: robertisaacBBN <robert.isaac@businessboomers.net>
Date:   Sat Dec 1 00:45:14 2018 +0200

    first commit
```

Thank the author of the original article @ https://www.shellhacks.com/git-particular-file-change-history/

Comment: in the second commit there is `(origin/first-branch)` after the commit id why is that?

Comment: Looks like it is little farther than my reach as of now, will push to my backlog and update when I have some clue. Or may be it is worth converting into another question :). Please post the link here, if you create a followup question.

Comment: You think it worth another question?

Comment: You still have a valid question, usually people may not read the comments and answer questions in the comments, particularly with low traffic questions. It is just a suggestion, Anyway, it is in my backlog. I hope to understand this myself, but may be after a while.